# An error occurs when training with R caret GBM. "Error in { : task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows"

Tags: r, package, r-caret, gbm

I want to solve the classification problem using [gbm](/questions/tagged/gbm). 
However, when using [caret](/questions/tagged/caret), the following error occurs.

> Error in {:
>      task 1 failed-"arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 336"

For reference, there is no NA or null value in my data. [Here is my data](https://github.com/kyrios05/R-Machine-Learning/blob/master/trainSet.csv)

There is no problem when I use [gbm](/questions/tagged/gbm) package. **If you know why this is happening when using Caret, please help me.**

Below is my code and session info.

```
if(!require(caret)){install.packages('caret', dep=TRUE);require(caret)}
if(!require(data.table)){install.packages('data.table', dep=TRUE);require(data.table)}
if(!require(gbm)){install.packages('gbm', dep=TRUE);require(gbm)}

trainSet <- fread(file="trainSet.csv")

trainSet$result <- as.factor(trainSet$result)

fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  repeats = 5
) 

#Error in { : task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 336"
model_gbm_caret<-train(result~ +size_delta+inserted_line+deleted_line+size, 
                       data = trainSet, 
                       method='gbm', 
                       trControl = fitControl,
                       verbose=TRUE)

#no error
model_gbm<-gbm(result~+size_delta+inserted_line+deleted_line+size, data=trainSet, cv.folds = 2)
```

**session info**

> ````
> (64-bit) Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601)
> Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949   
> LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                 [5]
> LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages: [1] gbm_2.1.5         data.table_1.12.8
> caret_6.0-86      ggplot2_3.3.0     lattice_0.20-40  
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4          
> pillar_1.4.3         compiler_3.5.3       gower_0.2.1         
> plyr_1.8.6            [6] iterators_1.0.12     class_7.3-15        
> tools_3.5.3          rpart_4.1-15         packrat_0.5.0        [11]
> ipred_0.9-9          lubridate_1.7.4      lifecycle_0.2.0     
> tibble_2.1.3         nlme_3.1-137         [16] gtable_0.3.0        
> pkgconfig_2.0.3      rlang_0.4.5          Matrix_1.2-18       
> foreach_1.5.0        [21] rstudioapi_0.11      parallel_3.5.3      
> prodlim_2019.11.13   e1071_1.7-3          gridExtra_2.3        [26]
> stringr_1.4.0        withr_2.1.2          dplyr_0.8.5         
> pROC_1.16.2          generics_0.0.2       [31] recipes_0.1.10      
> stats4_3.5.3         nnet_7.3-13          grid_3.5.3          
> tidyselect_1.0.0     [36] glue_1.3.2           R6_2.4.1            
> survival_3.1-11      lava_1.6.7           reshape2_1.4.3       [41]
> purrr_0.3.3          magrittr_1.5         ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2
> splines_3.5.3        scales_1.1.0         [46] codetools_0.2-16    
> MASS_7.3-51.5        rsconnect_0.8.16     assertthat_0.2.1    
> timeDate_3043.102    [51] colorspace_1.4-1     stringi_1.4.6       
> munsell_0.5.0        crayon_1.3.4  ```
> ````

Appreciate your help!

Comment: OP has noted there is no NA, and in the referenced post, there is no solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues, if you look at what you are trying to predict, it really doesn't make sense:

```
library(gbm)
library(data.table)
library(caret)

trainSet <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyrios05/R-Machine-Learning/master/trainSet.csv")

table(trainSet$result)

  1   8   9  10  11  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  22  23  24  26  28  30  31  33 
  3   3   3   2  24   3   8   3   4   2  12   5  41   5   3  63   5   3   4   3 
 36  38  39  42  43  44  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59 
  3   3   2   5   6   2   2   3  28  14   4   3   5   3   3  10   8   2   6   6 
 60  61  62  65  67  70  72  73  74  75  76  77  79  80  81  82  83  85  87  88 
  5   9  10   3   5   4 813 257   6   3   9   9   2   3   3   6   2   5   3   6 
 90  92  93  94  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 
  3   2  20  13   5   3   3   9  42   2   2   3   7   2   2   4   2  13   2   3 
112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 
  3  12   3   2   4   5   3   2
```

You are trying to run a classification on what looks like discrete values. And if I run the gbm, it runs but throws up error because there are too many label classes and too little data!

```
trainSet$result = factor(trainSet$result)

model_gbm<-gbm(result~+size_delta+inserted_line+deleted_line+size, data=trainSet, cv.folds = 2)
Distribution not specified, assuming multinomial ...
Warning messages:
1: In predict.gbm(model, newdata = my.data, n.trees = best.iter.cv) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In predict.gbm(model, newdata = my.data, n.trees = best.iter.cv) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

If it is indeed classification, you can reduce it to 3 classes:

```
trainSet$label = as.character(trainSet$result)
trainSet$label[!trainSet$label %in% c(72,73)] <- "others"

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=2) 
model_gbm_caret<-train(label~ +size_delta+inserted_line+deleted_line+size, 
                       data = trainSet, 
                       method='gbm', 
                       trControl = fitControl,
                       verbose=TRUE,distribution="multinomial")
```

Or you run a regression (which I hope is the intended):

```
trainSet <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyrios05/R-Machine-Learning/master/trainSet.csv")
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number=2) 
model_gbm_caret<-train(result ~ +size_delta+inserted_line+deleted_line+size, 
                       data = trainSet, 
                       method='gbm', 
                       trControl = fitControl,
                       verbose=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you!! you are my life saver!!! I have one more question. Is there any recommendation for 'When there are y classes, how much data are needed?'

Comment: it depends on your data right... how diverse is each class, meaning how many samples of each class do you need to distinguish one from the other.. there's no easy answer to this unfortunately...

Comment: Thank you. I don't forget your help!!